# Erro TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_dim' ao instanciar objeto de rede neural convulucional

Tags: python, classes, redes-neurais

Fiz um curso sobre redes neurais aplicadas ao processamento de linguagem natural e agora estou tentando instanciar um objeto baseado na classe construída em aula (com algumas modificações, pois meus dados são diferentes).

O objetivo é classificar três sentimentos, todos baseados em texto.

Quando instancio a classe abaixo, obtenho o seguinte erro:

> 'TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_dim''.

Não vi `output_dim` na documentação do Keras, do qual minha classe herda, e tampouco coloquei esse parâmetro no meu método construtor `__init__`.Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

```
class DCNN(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, 
               vocab_size,
               emb_dim= 128,
               nb_filters = 50,
               ffn_units=512,
               nb_classes = 3,
               dropout_rate = 0.1,
               training = False,
               name = 'dcnn'):
    super(DCNN, self).__init__(name = name)

    self.embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_dim = 128)
    self.bigram = layers.Conv1D(filters = nb_filters, kernel_size=2, 
                                   padding = 'same', 
                                   activation = 'relu')
    self.trigram = layers.Conv1D(filters = nb_filters, kernel_size=3, 
                                   padding = 'same', 
                                   activation = 'relu')
    self.fourgram = layers.Conv1D(filters = nb_filters, kernel_size=4, 
                                   padding = 'same', 
                                   activation = 'relu')

    self.pool = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()

    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(units = ffn_units, activation= 'relu')

    self.dropout = layers.Dropout(rate = dropout_rate)

    self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units = nb_classes, activation= 'softmax')

  def call(self, inputs, training):
    x = self.embedding(inputs) #inicio do fluxo da rede neural, embedding
    x_1 = self.bigram(x)
    x_1 = self.pool(x_1)
    x_2 = self.trigram(x)
    x_2 = self.pool(x_2)
    x_3 = self.fourgram(x)
    x_3 = self.pool(x_3)

    merged = tf.concat([x_1, x_2, x_3], axis = -1) ##concatena o output do pooling
    merged = self.dense_1(merged) #liga os dados da concatenação à camada densa
    merged = self.dropout(merged, training) #zera porção dos neuronios
    output = self.last_dense(merged) #liga camada de drop out nessa camada

    return output 

#instanciação 

dcnn = DCNN(vocab_size = 3276, emb_dim = 100, nb_filters = 100,
            ffn_units = 256, nb_classes = 3, 
            dropout_rate = 0.2)
```

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_dim'

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. Sugiro postar o erro completo, pois do jeito que está é difícil saber qual parte do código gera o erro. Sugiro também postar as ferramentas que está usando, de onde vem esse `layers`? Do `from tensorflow.keras import layers`?

Comment: Acredito que o erro é na chamada do `layers.Embedding`. Veja [aqui](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/)

Comment: Muito obrigado, Paulo. Troquei o emb_dim pelo output_dim. Outro usuário também já tinha me sinalizado. OBrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro aponta para a linha linha:

```
--->  self.embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_dim = 128)
```

Checando a [documentação do Keras sobre Embedding layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/), podemos ver que esta  camada recebe como parâmetros obrigatórios um `input_dim` e um `output_dim`. No seu código, só é passado o `input_dim` como `vocab_size`, mas falta o `output_dim`. Por isso o erro

> missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_dim'

Ainda na documentação, não existe um parâmetro chamado `emb_dim`, o que me leva a crer que você trocou o `output_dim` pelo `emb_dim` e que o correto seria:

```
self.embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=128)
```

Comment: You nailed it! hehehe. Obrigado, era isso mesmo. Que cirurgia vc fez no código. Eu já tinha tentado de tudo. Funcionou com o seu ajuste.